# UITableView: How to set clipsToBounds to Yes for cells only?

Tags: ios, uitableview

UITableView has the "clipsToBound" flag, if the flag is set to "No", the following is displayed Figure 1, but when scrolling the table the looks changes to the following - Figure 2.
Is there any way to set clipsToBounds to Yes for cells only, so that this wouldn’t apply to the header? (The result should be as on Figure 3).

http://monosnap.com/image/OkeTGPdQcfnQj12ReIzHGNlja

Comment: are circular A,B's in section header or they are in the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Put all views into one view, then put that view into `UITableViewCell`, then set `clipsToBound` to that view.

Also try to set `clipsToBound` to `UITableView`'s `ContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom cell set clipToBounds = YES in - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier.

If you use default cell do the following

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DefaultTableCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.clipToBounds = YES;
```